# How to show advertisements in my Activity?

Tags: android

I want to put an advertisement in my application. I set the advertisement layout size. But the problem is when I run this application in device, the advertisement layout size is decrease or increase depending on the device height.

I have multiple layout in my screen so I gave weight property but weight was sometimes increase or decrease.

Here, is my xml layout in which I set the layout for the advertisement:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@color/main_background"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_weight="0.09">
        <LinearLayout

            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:background="@color/spinner_bg_color"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp">
            <Spinner
                android:id="@+id/spinner"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            </Spinner>

        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp">
            <ListView
                android:id="@+id/lst_player"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="@color/main_background"
        android:layout_weight="0.65">
        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/adbar"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent">
        </FrameLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

The advertisement is loaded perfectly but the problem is layout height.

How to set the layout height for the advertisement where my activity has more than one or two layouts?

Please, help me to solve this issue.

Comment: Change the `android:layout_weight="0.09"` to `android:layout_weight="1"` and remove the `android:layout_weight="0.65"` entirely from the `FrameLayout`'s container `LinearLayout`. Also, change the `android:layout_height="fill_parent"` on the last two widgets to `android:layout_height="wrap_content"`. This way, the secondary LinearLayout will occupy the entire height and leave enough for the ad to display properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove your `FrameLayout` from the last inner `LinearLayout` and assign width `match_parent` and height `wrap_content`. I assume that you add ads programmatically to adbar so don´t forget to set Adview as SMART_BANNER.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@color/main_background"
    android:orientation="vertical" >


        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:background="@color/spinner_bg_color"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp">
            <Spinner
                android:id="@+id/spinner"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            </Spinner>

        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp">
            <ListView
                android:id="@+id/lst_player"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
        </LinearLayout>

    <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/adbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        </FrameLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Hope it helps!!

Comment: if i give my layout height 0dp then where is my listview item is display?

Comment: umm i got your point, your listview is not showing correctly, LinearLayout with weight 0.09 is useless in this case I'll edit my answer

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't add this as a comment. So posting it as an answer. Your layout has a logical problem. You're weighting layout heights right? So in case of weighting heights, you need to set the android:layout_height="0dp" so that the weight takes effect perfectly.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@color/main_background"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_weight="0.09">
        <LinearLayout

            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:background="@color/spinner_bg_color"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp">
            <Spinner
                android:id="@+id/spinner"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            </Spinner>

        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp">
            <ListView
                android:id="@+id/lst_player"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:background="@color/main_background"
        android:layout_weight="0.65">
        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/adbar"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent">
        </FrameLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```